# vue vita (main.ts) vps server not working

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue. While installing VUE, I installed it with ts (main.ts). When I send it to the server, I get an error: Failed to load module script:

Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/vnd.trolltech.linguist" . Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

ssh "tsc" command run error log:

error TS6305: Output file '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/src/router/index.d.ts' has not been built from source file '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/src/router/index.ts'. The file is in the program because: Matched by include pattern 'src/**/*.ts' in '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/tsconfig.json'

tsconfig.json:10:14 10 "include": ["src//*.ts","src//.js", "src/**/.d.ts", "src//*.tsx", "src/App.vue", "src/customFolder//*.ts"], ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ File is matched by include pattern specified here.

error TS6305: Output file '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/src/stores/index.d.ts' has not been built from source file '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/src/stores/index.ts'. The file is in the program because: Matched by include pattern 'src/**/*.ts' in '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/tsconfig.json'

tsconfig.json:10:14 10 "include": ["src//*.ts","src//.js", "src/**/.d.ts", "src//*.tsx", "src/App.vue", "src/customFolder//*.ts"], ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ File is matched by include pattern specified here.

Comment: It's unknown what you did and how you "installed it", but it looks like you try to load .ts file in a browser without a build step, which cannot be done. Refer to the official Vue guide regarding a common project setup